# Acceptable header file for clang based compiler

Tags: c++builder

I have some code that was previously compiled and working in C++Builder 6.  I want to recompile it in 10.4.2 and build 32-bit and 64-bit Windows targets.

The existing code compiles using the classic compiler, but when I try to compile with the clang compiler, I am getting the dreaded ICE:

> Internal compiler error: 0 @ 00000000

By using `#ifdef`s to remove sections of code, I have tracked it down to the way the functions are declared.  Nothing I have tried works, which makes me think I must have missed something very fundamental.

The original code that still works with the classic compiler:

```cpp
extern "C" {
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) GetLogonSIDFromToken (HANDLE hToken, PSID *ppsid);
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) GetCurrentProcessLogonSID (PSID *ppsid);
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) GetLogonSIDFromAccountName(char *lpszUserName, PSID *ppsid);
VOID WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) FreeLogonSID (PSID *ppsid);
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) AddAceToNewSecurityDescriptor(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd, PSID psid, DWORD dwType, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwMask);
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) SetUserObjectNullDacl(HANDLE hObject);
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) AddAceToUserObject(HANDLE hObject, PSID psid, DWORD dwType, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwMask);
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) AddAceToWindowStation(HWINSTA hwinsta, PSID psid);
BOOL WINAPI __declspec(dllexport) AddAceToDesktop(HDESK hdesk, PSID psid);
}
```

Now I have tried lots of things, and looked into the Windows SDK headers, but if I put this into my code:

```cpp
extern "C" {
// this is lifted directly from winbase.h
WINADVAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
LogonUserExW (
    _In_            LPCWSTR lpszUsername,
    _In_opt_        LPCWSTR lpszDomain,
    _In_opt_        LPCWSTR lpszPassword,
    _In_            DWORD dwLogonType,
    _In_            DWORD dwLogonProvider,
    _Outptr_opt_ PHANDLE phToken,
    _Outptr_opt_ PSID  *ppLogonSid,
    _Outptr_opt_result_bytebuffer_all_(*pdwProfileLength) PVOID *ppProfileBuffer,
    _Out_opt_       LPDWORD pdwProfileLength,
    _Out_opt_       PQUOTA_LIMITS pQuotaLimits
    );

/*
BOOL
WINAPI
GetLogonSIDFromToken(
    _In_ HANDLE hToken,
    _Outptr_opt_ PSID *ppsid
    );
*/
/*
BOOL
APIENTRY
GetLogonSIDFromToken(
    _In_ HANDLE hToken,
    _Outptr_opt_ PSID *ppsid
    );
*/}
```

It compiles fine (but obviously doesn't have declarations for my functions), but if I uncomment either the second or third declaration, I get the ICE error.

Can anyone provide any pointers (no pun intended) for me, please?

Comment: Could it be that you have some project paths still pointing at classic include directories or library directories or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the thought Ted, I don't think that's the case, the only headers I am using that are not shipped with the product is this one.  I can't see how the inclusion of another header or path would mean the compiler is happy to accept the first declaration (a Windows API call) but no variation (that I have tried) of my own declared function.

Comment: Ok, it was a long shot :)

Comment: Found the issue which is not at all what I expected … I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not what it looks like.**

The code compiles fine with no function declarations in the header, but the problem is not in the header itself.  There are two functions in the file that use __try __finally (Microsoft extensions) which are officially supported by clang, but in one of them there was a label at the beginning of the __finally block.  Removing the label allowed the code to compile.

```cpp
__finally
{
blockexit:
  ...
```

Removing the `blockexit:` label allows the code to compile.

I have no idea why the code compiles fine if there are no function declarations in the header ...

Thanks to all who looked at this.